# How to set Ubuntu as default OS, XPS 15?

Tags: dual-boot

I dual boot on XPS 15, the only problem is when I start it up, it defaults to Windows. I have to shut it down again, start it up while holding F12, select Ubuntu, and select Ubuntu at the grub screen.

Is there an option to change this behavior?

Comment: That is sadly solved accessing your BIOS and changing the boot order. From Ubuntu your can't do this.

Comment: What do you mean, from Ubuntu you can't do this? You usually can't reset any Bios options while running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F2 should bring up the full UEFI options, there I believe you will be able to permanently change the boot options. Otherwise when I was dual booting Window 8 and Ubuntu 12.04, running boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair forced the UEFI to boot to a grub menu which defaulted to Ubuntu. I should mention though that I am running an XPS 8500 desktop.

Comment: I had been at that screen, but I didn't read the very bottom - it says you need to F5 to change the order, selecting "ubuntu" and pressing enter wasn't enough :)